# Shiny validate not working on zero row data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code....for some reason, `validate` does not kick in and the `plot` command runs with an error. What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df <- df[-1, ]
    validate(
      need(nrow(df),
           "Not Enough Data")
    )
    plot(df$x, df$y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Everything from the data frame perspective looks fine:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)
df
  x y
1 1 1

df <- df[-1, ]
df
[1] x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

nrow(df)
[1] 0

names(df)
[1] "x" "y"
```

Comment: See `?need`, `Details` section. The `0` result of the expression in `need` is not considered a failure, and so the message is not triggered. `FALSE`, `NULL` and other objects are considered failures. Keep in mind that in R `0` and `FALSE` are different. The answer below should solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
shiny::need(0, "Won't say anything")
shiny::need(NULL, "Will say something")
shiny::need(FALSE, "Will say something")
```

Try:

```
need(nrow(data)>0)
```

Comment: OMG - I am so dumb...need to get off screen. Kept thinking it enforces nrow(df) not zero. Oh well...of course not. Thanks.

Comment: Totally...I just blanked there and kept making silly mistake. Thanks! Whew.